# Undefined behavior in dlclose() when interface was introduced

Tags: c++, c, linux, protocol-buffers, .so

Here is my code structure:

**A.cpp**

```
class InterfaceA {
  public:
    virtual void hello(googleProtobuf::Message msg) = 0;
    virtual ~InterfaceA() {}
};

class A : public InterfaceA{
 public:
    void hello(googleProtobuf::Message msg){
    }
    ~A() {}
};
```

**B.cpp**

```
struct callback{
  void (*fn) (void* callback_data);
};

class B{
void* handle;
struct callback cbacks_;
interfaceDLL* dll_x;

public:
  B() : cbacks_({B_fn}){
    handle = dlopen("mydll", RTLD_NOW);
    auto init_fn = dlsym(handle,"initFn"));
    if(init_fn != nullptr){
      dll_x = init_fn(cbacks_);
    }
  }
  ~B() {
    if(dll_x->deinit != nullptr)
      dll_x->deinit(dll_x);

    if(handle != null)
      dlclose(handle);
  }

  void B_fn(void* callback_data) {
    A a;
    a.hello(cast(callback_data));
  }
}
```

**Dll.cpp**

```
extern "C"
interfaceDll* initFn(const callback* c);

class dllclass : public interfaceDll {
callback c;
public:
  dllclass(const callback& cb) : c(cb) {}
  
  void transferData(void* data){
    c.fn(data);
  }

  void deinit(interfaceDLL* dll_x) {
    if(dll_x != nullptr)
      delete dll_x;
  }
};

interfaceDll* initFn(const callback* c) {
  if(c != nullptr) {
    return new dllclass(*c);
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

My code was working (maybe out of sheer luck) when I did not have `InterfaceA` and had just `class A`. But I had to introduce `InterfaceA` for a purpose and when I did the code crashed in linux(sigsegv) and gave an undefined behavior (memory corruption sort) in another linux machine. When I comment out the `dlClose()` line, everything seems to work fine.
I do not want the dll to be in memory so I want to close it. Is there a reason why the introduction of `InterfaceA` cause trouble? Or did it bring out an existing issue? If so, is there any way I can find the issue?

This is part of a very big codebase. Please let me know if any more info is needed or something is unclear.

TIA. :)

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in some other code that you haven't shown.    Presumably, by introducing `InterfaceA`, you have changed memory layout of your program in some way.   For example, changing the size of an `A` (since it now has a virtual function, and didn't before) can have the effect of changing what is placed in memory immediately after the `A` by some other code.   If it so happens that memory is being tromped by some badly-behaved code, the symptoms can change because something else is now at that memory location.

Comment: `interfaceDll` is missing in your example. But the real problem is, that `cbacks_({B_fn})`  shouldn't even be compiling. You are treating a non-static member function as a raw function pointer, which was broken to begin with (you need the base object as context!).

Comment: Please create a [mcve], I most certainly won't install _googleProtobuf_ to compile your program.